# Link between html and css not working, what do I do?

Tags: html, css

As the title says, I am really new to html and I have run into a problem where whenever I try to open my file the css portion is just not there.

Here is a part of my .html code

```
<head>
<title>Page name</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
```

Yes, my css file is called style.css.

Comment: The browsers developers tools/error console is the place to look.

Comment: probably the href address does not refer to the correct directory

Answer (score 1):

Is your `style.css` in the same folder as your `index.html`?
The correct way to link to it then would be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
```

Because at the moment your HTML is looking for the `style.css` inside the `css` folder located in the same folder as your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Move all files to the root of whatever it is (if you’re testing locally) and try that. It seems to me like a directory issue.

Answer (score 0):

based in your question, i supose that your folder is something like that:

```
rootFolder->
          js->
               something.js
          css->
               style.css
          index.html
```

if is this the case, verify if your css is valid and correct, if the structure of folder is different, so this is the error.